# Process.Start("microsoft-edge:") throws Win32Exception in dot net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, microsoft-edge

When I execute the following line of code:

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:");
```

Or

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://localhost");
```

It gives me this error:

> **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:** 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

When I run `microsoft-edge:` using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> it works.

When I run the same code in .net framework it works.

I'm using `.netcore 3.0.0-preview6-27804-01`

Any idea why this is happening?

---

Edit:

These are not working either:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\Windows\System32\LaunchWinApp.exe:http://localhost");
Process.Start(@"http://localhost");
```

All other executables on my system work.

Also this is working too but I can't open a specific webpage with it:

```
Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge");
```

Comment: wow! another unreasonable vote down :-)

Comment: Sadly none of the answer tells the exact root cause, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8 "The default is true on .NET Framework apps and false on .NET Core apps."

Comment: thanks @LexLi this means that the better solution is to set `UseShellExecute = true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot simply open a url with the expected call `Process.Start("url");`

You have to create a `ProcessStartInfo` and pass your browser and url as arguments:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start microsoft-edge:http://localhost") { CreateNoWindow = true });
```

*(edit) The use of `ProcessStartInfo` is required because we need to set its `CreateNoWindow = true` to prevent cmd window from showing up*.

But as this code not only can be run on a Windows machine, i'd consider using something more cross-platform specific like this (https://brockallen.com/2016/09/24/process-start-for-urls-on-net-core/):

```
public void OpenBrowser(string url)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it with `OpenBrowser("http://localhost");`

Comment: Thank you very much! It's help me a lot. 


We can add this 

url = url.Replace("&", "^&");

before 
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });

Because cmd.exe will recognize ^& into &.

Comment: This is a great answer. I've been looking for a cross platform way to launch a local HTML file in a browser, and this is it!

Answer (score 7):

The exact root cause is indicated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8

"The default is true on .NET Framework apps and false on .NET Core apps."

This means the direct solution is to set UseShellExecute.  The following is basically the same as the original except making an explicit Process object to modify a setting.

```
       Process pWeb = new Process();
       pWeb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
       pWeb.StartInfo.FileName = "microsoft-edge:http://localhost";
       pWeb.Start();
```

Credit to @Lex Li and @Bizhan for their comments leading to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This variation seems to do the job as well:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("msedge") { 
  UseShellExecute = true, 
  Arguments = "http://localhost" });
```

It avoids the strangeness of the `microsoft-edge:<url>` syntax thus allowing for more [chrome arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to be passed in the usual way.

If anyone knows of a reason to avoid this, feel free to speak up :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows `Run` window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) know how to resolve "`microsoft-edge:`" to the Path Of Executable. When you call it through `Run` window, it first resolves to the path. Then the actual executable from that path is executed.

With `Process.Start`, there is no this resolution of path. It only look for some paths like application path or `PATH` variables. Obviously, it does not find the executable to run and hence the error.

> If you have a path variable declared in your system using quotes, you must fully qualify that path when starting any process found in that location. Otherwise, the system will not find the path. For example, if c:\mypath is not in your path, and you add it using quotation marks: path = %path%;"c:\mypath", you must fully qualify any process in c:\mypath when starting it.
>
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_)

Note that command line parameters are not allowed by this overload:

> This overload does not allow command-line arguments for the process. If you need to specify one or more command-line arguments for the process, use the Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) or Process.Start(String, String) overloads.